# squid cache becoming too large on widnows

Tags: proxy, squid

so here is my scenario.
i have configured squid 3.5.26 on windows server 2012 r2. squid cache folder becomes too large day by day.i want to limit that cache without effecting any process of squid.that squid can cache maximum 5GB. i have search a lot but didn't found any solution.any help will be appreciated.
waiting for your kind response.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Just go into squid folder and open squid.conf file.
2. Change your script from `Cache_dir` and assign the space to the cache folder in Mbs as given below.

   ```
   cache_dir ufs E:/Squid/var/cache/squid 5000 16 256
   ```